# How to create a tree type menu structure in phonegap using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, cordova

I am creating an app in which i want to create a menu with submenus in the panel i tried to create a collapse with the list view. but the issue is in some menu sub menu list is large and when i tries to scroll the panel menu whole page started scrolling along with header and footer. So i tried to do some changes in the css so that only panel can be scrolled but when i run it on the browser it worked great and when i run the same on the Android 4.2 in emulator and on the samsung phone it didnt worked.
But when i tries to run it on the HTC desire with Android os2.3.5 it worked.
can anyone tell whats the reason for this.
I used **JQUERY MOBILE 1.3.1.js** and also tired **JQUERY MOBILE 1.3.2** but same result.
Any Idea is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.ajaxshake.com/en/JS/2410581/jquery-mobile-menu-example-jquerymobileexamples.html

Comment: hey but i want to create it in the panel and when i tried to create it using collapsible when the length of panel is greater at that time page scroll along with the panel in android 4.2 but works grt on 2.3.5